# iOS Split View - Reload Detail View

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am new to making iOS apps. I have currently built a Split View based app. There is an array in the left had table and what ever is touched it loads the relating xib file in the detail view.

Now I want a home button to work. I want this to basically reload the DetailViewController to scratch. I have got it working like this so far:

```
- (IBAction)homeButtonPressed:(id)sender;
{


    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailView" owner:self options:nil];//load xib
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;//hide the home button
    [self setTitle:@"Driveway Code"];//display the title
}
```

But the problem with this is that it still has the row selected in the left hand side. And I cannot seem to un select it.

If you could provide me with help either to reload the split view again or to just unselect the row. I would be happy. Thanks :)

UPDATE:

I have now go this:

```
- (IBAction)homeButtonPressed:(id)sender;
{



    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

    [self setTitle:@"Driveway Code"];
    DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init]; [dvc setTableView:tableView];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:detailItem animated:YES];



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to select row programmatically:

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

and this one for deselect

```
- (void)deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot seem to implement this into my DetailViewController.m. Please could you show me? Thanks. :)

Comment: You should have the reference to your table view `tableView` in `DetailViewController` and when you need just call `[tableView deselectTowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];`

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't got that. Where should this be and how shall the code look? :/

Comment: Define `@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;` in DetailViewController.h. In `@implementation DetailViewController` write `@synthesize tableView;`. And, finally, when after initializing `DetailViewController` write `DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init]; [dvc setTableView:tableView];` where tableView is your left table view =)

Comment: Thanks. But I am having issues adding the last line. In the detailviewcontroller.m it isn't accepting. Where's the initialisation?

Comment: Got the last line in within my IBAction but it doesn't work. Just doesn't unselect it. Am I still mean to be using the code which is in your answer?

Comment: Please, post code where you are creating your DetailViewController's. It should be located in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Where is `homeButtonPressed:` method implemented? In what controller? In root view or detail view?

Comment: In the DetailViewController.h '- (IBAction)homeButtonPressed:(id)sender;//Home Button'

Comment: Try to implement it in root view controller, that supplies data to main table view.

Comment: Nope, won't have it. I won't @synthesize in the rootviewcontroller.m

Comment: Then find method where detailviewcontroller that implements that method is created and post it here.